# how to enable f.inputs to render templates when there is a partial with that name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, semantic-markup, cocoon-gem

in activeadmin form when I do:

```
  form(:html => { :multipart => true })  do |f|
    f.inputs
  end
```

it shows all the fields nicely, and when it comes to `belongs_to` field it shows them as a collection but I want to replace this collection with a `template` of my `belongs_to` field.

For example when it will see

```
f.inputs :product
```

it will render `_product.html.erb` partial something like this.

I know I can do:

```
  form(:html => { :multipart => true })  do |f|
    f.input :field_name1
    f.input :field_name2
    ...
    f.input :field_name3
    render 'x_fields'
  end
```

But it is my least favourite, the problem with this is that, when I'll be updating my database I need to update these fields too which is not required for `f.inputs`. Thats why I like to use f.inputs.

Comment: Something like 
 f.template.render partial: 'x_fields' ?

Comment: I want `f.inputs :product` to render `_product.html.erb` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Well, currently using this as a solution:

```
def form_inputs_for(m)
    columns=m.columns.map{|c| c.name}
    columns=columns.select{|s| !(s.end_with?"_id" or s.end_with?"_at" or s=="id") }
    columns.each do  |a|
        input a
    end
end
```

and at form:

```
  form(:html => { :multipart => true })  do |f| 
    f.inputs do
      form_inputs_for(Cpu)
    end
  end
```

also at my blog: http://www.sadafnoor.com/blog/activeadmin-semantic-input-partial-and-f-inputs-togather/